# javascript doesn't convert special characters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, encoding, character-encoding

I've got a form where there's 2 select boxes. The second one changes everytime the user selects a different value in the first select box. The first time I load the form and populate with data everything is fine. But then when the user changes the first select box and I repopulate the second select box with an ajax function the text doesn't show special characters. I've been debuging and the data from the database it's ok, so I guess it's in the javascript part that's failing. Here's the ajax code:

```
function alter_data() {          
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_data.php',
        type: 'POST',        
        data:jQuery('#Form1').serializeArray(),              
        success: function(data) {            
            jQuery('#2selectbox').html(data); 

        }
    }); 
}
```

So I printed the data in the php file before I send it and it's fine. Here in the ajax function I already tried to change html() function to text() function and also tried text(data).html().

The files are encoded in ANSI and the database in Latin1_General_CI_AI.

Thank you :)

EDIT:

A print of the problem I have:

https://gyazo.com/3f1cafda66da88e3929399bb04160e23

Comment: can you show some part of that response with special characters?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've haded in the post

Comment: check your current file encoding

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  It's ANSI

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest already tried that :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a dumb thing. This is a big project that was already made when I start working on it and this error was hapenning because the php configuration file didn't have a default_charset. All I had to do is add this parameter and then things start to work propely.

Thank you for your help :)